# ArrayList capacity and JVM memory usage

Tags: java, memory, out-of-memory, heap-memory

I computed the following code and I tried it with Xmx4096m and got out of memory error.

Does that mean even though the size of each list is only 1, but it's taking more heap space because the capacity is set to 100000000?

```
List<List<String>> allList = new ArrayList<>();
for (int i = 0; i < 100000000; i++) {
    List<String> list = new ArrayList<>(100000000);
    list.add("1");
    allList.add(list);
}
```

Comment: It looks that way, yes! Have you attempted the loop with say half the amount?

Comment: You're creating huge backing arrays.

Comment: @bdavies6086 I tried it with just i < 50, it still failed.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels I don't understand then, if the size of each list is only 1 and the capacity is only indicating how many items it can potentially hold, then why should I get out of memory error? Shouldn't the actual memory of each list be really small?

Comment: Your concept of capacity is wrong. It creates a huge backing array, regardless of whether you fill it to that size or not. You should use capacity for efficiency and not for maximal holding capacity since it doesn't represent that. You're far better off in this situation using the default ArrayList constructor and letting your lists increase in size and capacity as needed.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels So what would be an optimal solution, in terms of memory management, if I have 2 lists, one should contain 1 item, the 2nd list should contain 100000000 items? Should I still use the default ArrayList constructor?

Comment: 100,000,000 items? I'd look into using sparse arrays or database for something like this.

Comment: new ArrayList<>(100000000);

will ideally consume 4 * 100000000 byte of space. The implementation is new Object[initialSize]. Initialize the arraylist with the size that is actually required. 1 if one object to be assigned and 100000000 if 100000000 are to assigned.